# Angular 2 http request is not hitting web api get method with a string parameter overload

Tags: c#, rest, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My problem is that the first Get method is called from this http request:
http://localhost:56690/api/testelements/?name=aeg

wouldn't I expect my this to hit the second (string overload) method since it has a string parameter?  How do I make it hit the second (string overload) method?

this is my web api controller in c#

```
// GET api/<controller>
public IEnumerable<TestElement> Get()
{
    return testelements;
}

// GET api/<controller>/searchString
//[HttpGet, Route("api/testelements/{name=name}")]
public IEnumerable<TestElement> Get(string searchString)
{
    return Array.FindAll(testelements, s => s.name.Contains(searchString));
}
```

for my angular service i have this typescript code

```
search(term: string): Observable<testelement[]> {
    return this.http
               .get(`api/testelements/?name=${term}`)
               .map(response => response.json() as testelement[]);
}
```

my WepApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I dont want it to override this function!:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var testelement = testelements.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.id == id);
    if (testelement == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(testelement);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/testelements/{searchString}")]
public IEnumerable<TestElement> Get(string searchString)
{
    return Array.FindAll(testelements, s => s.name.Contains(searchString));
}


search(term: string): Observable<testelement[]> {
    return this.http
               .get(`api/testelements/` + ${term}) //append your search term at end of your Url.
               .map(response => response.json() as testelement[]);
}
```

Url to test from browser: [http:yourUrl/api/testelements/123](http://http:yourUrl/api/testelements/1)

> **Update**
>
> I dont want it to override this function!:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var testelement = testelements.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.id == id);
    if (testelement == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(testelement);
}
```

If you don't want to override the above method, then you need to change the Attribute route of this function,

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/test/{searchString}")] // previous route [HttpGet, Route("api/testelements/{searchString}")]   
public IEnumerable<TestElement> Get(string searchString)
{
    return Array.FindAll(testelements, s => s.name.Contains(searchString));
}
```

If you need more info on routing, [Check this out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints)

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for ${term}    

argument of type search '{term: string}' is not assignable of type 'RequestOptionArgs'  Object literal may specify known parameters

are you sure this is what you used?

Comment: Actually got it, it just needed + '`${term}`' instead of + ${term}. im going to edit your answer. thank you for your help!!!

Comment: one problem is that it also overrides this function...

        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            var testelement = testelements.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.id == id);
            if (testelement == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(testelement);
        }